# Using crude but effective stratification & cong to implement transitivity of `=`

Tags: dependent-type, proof-review, universe-polymorphism

Suppose I have

- `cong : {A B : Type} (f : A -> B) (p : a = b) : f a = f b`
- `coe : (A : I -> Type) -> A 0 -> A 1`

It is a common pattern in less crude type theory that we implement `=-trans` as `=-trans : {a b c : A} (p : a = b) (q : b = c) : a = c := coe (cong (\x. a = x) q) p`
But in this case, `\x => a = x` is of type `A -> Type`, where the codomain and domain does not live in the same universe, as demanded by `cong`.
Is there a clever way to add some lifts in `=-trans` to make the code type check or do I have to inline `cong`?

Comment: What about having `A` and `B` live at possibly different universes? Would this solve your issue? Otherwise, if you start playing around with lifting, I fear you will only be able to prove a degraded version of your goal, typically something like `lift a = lift c` (an equality that relates the liftings of `a` and `c` to the type `A` moved one universe up).